# ReadWords instead of Bytes

Tags: c, byte, i2c, words

I am using I2C communication and I need to read words instead of bytes but i am stuck.
To read bytes I do:

```
void I2CReadBytes(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint8_t *value)
{
    uint8_t i=0;
    I2C_MasterSendStart(devAddr, I2C_WRITE_XFER_MODE);
    I2C_MasterWriteByte(regAddr);
    I2C_MasterSendRestart(devAddr, I2C_READ_XFER_MODE);
    while (i++ < (length-1)) {
        *value++ = I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_ACK_DATA);
    }
    *value = I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_NAK_DATA);
    I2C_MasterSendStop();
}
```

What if I want to readWords? I have to use int16_t *value but after that I'm stuck with

```
while (i++ < (length-1)) {
            *value++ = I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_ACK_DATA);
        }
        *value = I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_NAK_DATA);
```

Thank you

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to write a word-reading function in terms of your existing byte-reading function, like this: `void I2CReadWords(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint16_t *value) { I2CReadBytes(devAddr, regAddr, length * 2, (uint8_t *)value); }`.  But you may have byte-ordering difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

bigendian

```
uint16_t ReadWord(void)
{
    uint16_t result = 0;
    uint8_t b;
    b = I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_ACK_DATA);
    result = b + I2C_MasterReadByte(I2C_ACK_DATA) << 8;
    return result; 
}
```

it does not check for any errors as I do not know if your one does

Comment: b is the LSB?It should be MSB first no?

Comment: Depending on the other side of the bus. I2C is byte oriented and the other device decides what the byte order is.